# Common-mode chokes in series

Tags: rf, series, interference, common-mode-choke

Is it common practice to combine common mode chokes back-to-back in series to eliminate/reduce RF interference in different frequency bands? As a random  example, placing [this](http://katalog.we-online.de/pbs/datasheet/744235110.pdf) in series with [this](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/filters/common-mode-chokes/839?k=&pkeyword=&pv1233=613&FV=ffe00347&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) in series to reduce/eliminate RF interference in both AM and FM bands. In the few PS schematics I've come across on the web I've only seen single chokes with low value capacitor networks afterwards to filter RF, haven't seen multiple chokes in series. Any caveats to doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes to caveats. The common mode choke is not magic, being instead one leg of a voltage divider. The common mode chock is the series element of the divider.
You need to provide a shunt element, for the choke to be effective. You can explore several shunting methods

(1) shunt between the +/- pairs only

(2) shunt from each of the differential wires to GND/RETURN

(3) combining 1 & 2

Comment: But why would you NEED to shunt the RF current to ground/chassis (other than additional attentuation)? I thought the purpose of the choke is to act as a high impedance to high frequency CM currents, reducing their effects on the signal/power line circuit. Why is shunting them a requirement?

Comment: @User7251 Think of the choke as a resistor. If the choke has, e.g., 1 kΩ at 100 MHz, then it would not help much if your device has a high-impedance input with many GΩ.

Comment: @CL: Ah, that makes sense. And I'm guessing then that if using method (2) above the capacitor network used for shunting should be optimized to have minimal impedance in the choke's highest impedance frequency range?

Comment: @User7251 It should have minimal impedance for the frequencies you want to filter out.